# PWM accuracy vs speed control accuracy

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, rotor-speed

For inverter closed-loop controlled PMSM motor, if we want to realize a high speed accuracy at steady state, say 0.2%, i.e., +/- 2rpm at 1000rpm, must the PWM accuracy be better that it? Or is it more about PWM resolution?

My understanding is that the PWM resolution must be better, say 12-bit, and then resolution is not a problem. One the other hand, PWM accuracy is affected by MCU clock, which is affected by external crystal/oscillator. If PWM accuracy must be better than motor control's accuracy, then I have to be very careful when selecting the components.

[updated]

Another issue is the motor speed measurement. For such higher accuracy motor speed control, I guess encoder is needed, and since 12-bit and even 15-bit incremental encoders are available, so I guess it is more on the speed detection algorithm to make sure the measured speed accuracy is better than 0.2%. Any suggestion on encoder processing algorithm?

The motor load is a slow changing one and the variation is roughly +/- 5%.

[update-2]

Let's not talk about cases like flywheels where the inertia is huge to help stabilize the speed. I think a proper analogy would be a blender blade driven by a PMSM motor with encoder, blending a small amount of fruits.

Comment: You're not looking at a truly linear relation, so for fine speed control you use speed feedback instead of voltage/current feedback.  For a constant load, an alternative is to measure actual speed output over the entire drive range and scale the duty cycle in software as necessary.  0.2% is fairly fine, so even with speed feedback you have a significant challenge without an engineering degree.  For pure speed measurement Hall sensors are common and for fine position which allows speed measurement you might want to look into rotary encoders.

Comment: I'm not an engineer so I won't write that as an answer unless one of the engineers confirms as there may be options I'm not seeing.  In the meantime, you should define your project better to improve your question.  What is the load?  Is it variable?  Do you need high precision or just high accuracy(precision would be tightly controlled speed, accuracy refers to how correct the speed is on average rather than how tight the control is.  Google "Precision VS Accuracy" if this is not clear.

Comment: If you need both high precision and high accuracy, you need a high switching frequency and a low delay on your control response and/or predictive feedback.

Comment: Hi, KH, thanks for your input. I added some update in my post to address your questions.  and I understand the difference between accuracy and precision. What I am looking for, I guess, is accuracy with precision.

Comment: You should probably add rough parameters for the wattage and voltage of your load as they are other difficulty factors.  If I think of anything else I'll let you know.  My skill level is high enough to see how your system would have to work and see some of the potential challenges, but far from high enough to actually design such a high performance circuit.  There may be some already existing commonly available solution, but I suspect building your own with 0.2% regulation is an expert level problem for an engineer.

Comment: You have a control loop to vary the pwm duty cycle in order to control the motor’s speed. The motor’s speed and the ability to change that speed (inertia) is significantly slower than your pwm signal (say 20kHz). So, 8 bit resolution on the pwm is probably more than enough to satisfy your speed precision requirements. Similarly with encoder resolution - speed is based in time, so there’s some integration happening. Being able to measure the instantaneous speed with sub-degree resolution is useless as the ability for the motor and everything connected to change speed significantly is not likely

Comment: Motors running on inverter speed controls are frequency driven. The PWM is creating a current profile that closely approximates a sine wave. It is the ability to accurately create this approximation which determines your ability to predict the motor speed. If you want to detect the load, you can do this by looking at motor current phase angle in relation to the inverter phase angle.

Comment: @Kartman, I tend to agree with you, but that basically means PWM resolution and accuracy will have no effect on motor speed control accuracy, which doesn't "feel" correct. Is there any articles or documents about it that I can refer to?

Comment: For that precisions you really need a closed loop control. A motor in service would have a somewhat varied load (even only dust on the bearings!) so you just can't estimate from the torque the real speed. Unless of course you are using a synch motor. Even BLDC uses hall sensors to determine rotor position (and speed control is easy then) but sensorless BLDC has big issues at low speeds

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio, what you said is not related to my question, but yes, the motor is closed-loop control and I just added it in the post.

Comment: If kartman's comment doesn't "feel" accurate consider an extremely heavy flywheel with low friction driven by a small motor. Simple on off control might be sufficient in that case, since the rpms would rise and fall very slowly with the motor on or off. The lower the inertia, the faster your system will have to respond. Having finer control of the motor output won't increase your accuracy, but it will make the control loop simpler due to less drastic accelerations being possible.

Comment: Not clear if the motor is DC brushed (controlled by voltage and current) or, since the word "inverter" is in the question, three phase synchronous or asynchronous (controlled by frequency). This is an important distinction, since basically everything depends on it!

Comment: Also you must tell us about settling time. If you want to reach the target rpm in a minute, then you can use a big dumb heavy flywheel. If you want to reach it in one second, then maybe no flywheel, and you have to replace dumb mass with smart control loop, which is sexier, and harder. Note settling time also applies to quick variations in load torque.

Comment: Note flywheels have safety issues, too. If one of your requirements is "stop rotation immediately when operator body part enters the danger zone"... or if the load can jam and get stuck... then you need low inertia, so no flywheel.

Comment: @bobflux thanks for the inputs and I have updated the post to address your questions. I think I want to know the steady state operation of small inertia applications.

Comment: OK! How many poles? I mean, what drive frequency do you need to achieve your 1000rpm? Also a rough estimation of voltage/current? And inertia is still relevant because you have to decide on how much the rotation speed can vary during a turn (wow/flutter).

Comment: Let's throw around some numbers to get a handle on the problem:
1000RPM is 16.6 revolutions per second. Each revolution takes 60milliseconds
+/- 0.2% is +/- 120microseconds
PWM frequency is 20kHz (for example), so you have 20,000/16.6 = 1250 PWM cycles per revolution. By using a technique called 'dithering' you'll get 1250 times the base resolution of the PWM signal. For if your PWM was 8 bits (256 steps) you'll be able to achieve a resolution 1000 times that which is near enough 15 bits worth. The control system would probably end up implementing dithering as part of its operation.

Comment: Further to BobFlux's comment regarding poles. There's torque ripple to consider. If the load is discontinuous - you mention a blender, then there'll be more instantaneous speed variation. There's been quite a bit of research done with high speed spindle motors for CNC machining centres where they are measuring each cut of the tool where high precision control is implemented. I'm not sure if you really need such level of precision.

Comment: @Kartman Yeah I think there is a compromise to make between number of bits (amplitude precision) and PWM period (phase precision) and in this case the latter will probably be a lot more important than the former. Hence, as you suggest, low-bit PWM (high PWM frequency) with dithering/noise shaping gives the advantages of both.

Comment: Knowing the currents and voltages involved would help in selecting the right switching frequency, too.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's not talk about cases like flywheels where the inertia is huge to help stabilize the speed

But we are.  With typical modern microcontrollers and their built-in PWM generators, and typical motors, the motor itself is a flywheel -- not to mention the blade you're putting on it.  Consider [this motor](https://www.maxongroup.com/maxon/view/category/motor?etcc_cu=onsite&etcc_med_onsite=Product&etcc_cmp_onsite=RE+Program&etcc_plc=Overview-Page-DC-Motors&etcc_var=%5bcom%5d%23en%23_d_&target=filter&filterCategory=re), which is *designed* to have low inertia (and is absurdly expensive for whacking fruit to bits).  It's a coreless motor, which means it has maybe five to twenty times less inertia than a brushless motor.

It has a mechanical time constant, by itself, of 4.87ms.  That means that this *absurdly quick-responding motor* acts like a 1st-order lowpass filter with a 3dB frequency of 32Hz.

To heap absurdity on absurdity, let's say you're driving the motor PWM with a super-cheap microprocessor like an Atmel 8-bit part, and that for some reason you've decided to use the 8-bit timers.  So you have an effective PWM resolution of 1 in 128.  Even an ATMega will handle updating the PWM at 10kHz -- so assume that.

Now, you've got a resolution of 1:128 -- which is way worse than the 1:500 (0.2%) that you're calling out.  If you simply dither the PWM at 625Hz, you can increase your effective resolution by a factor of 16 -- that puts you well above the 1:500 that you need.  Better yet, implement a simple 1st-order sigma-delta modulator in your software, then you'll extend the effective resolution of the PWM by approximately 300, or a hair over 15 bits.  You could contemplate implementing an even higher-order sigma-delta, but you're already at a ridiculous level of resolution compared to what you need, so why go there?

Answer (score 1):

The **accuracy** of a PWM signal may be much better than you think. If you really mean the accuracy of the **duty factor** then it is independent of small variations in the processor's clock frequency. The duty factor is the ratio of the pulse high time to the pulse period, and both of these are integer multiples of the processor clock frequency. So, the actual clock frequency cancels out.

The only way the accuracy would suffer is if the clock frequency changed significantly **during each period** of the PWM output. That is certainly possible, but the effect is probably much less than absolute crystal accuracy and temperature variation.

Having said all that, I don't know if this is the best way to control your motor.

Comment: The duty factor cancels out the clock inaccuracy makes a lot of sense! In that case, the resolution of PWM seems more important because it decides how fine the duty ratio could be. Of course, the crystal accuracy (+/-0.5% is quite common)  and temperature drift will also affect it. I am curious about your last statement. What in your opinion could be a better way to control the motor in the assumed blender scenario if the speed accuracy is required?

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear. I don't have the right background to recommend techniques for motor speed control, I just wanted to address the PWM accuracy issue.

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy of an optical encoder is important to factor in. The optical encoder measures discrete changes in angular position, so your position error is at most one encoder count. This encoder error will manifest itself in the speed calculation because you need to differentiate the angular position (\$\theta\$) with respect to the sampling time (\$T\$) to get angular angular velocity (\$\omega\$). Differentiation is done numerically using the current encoder count \$\theta_{i}\$ and the last sampled encoder count \$\theta_{i-1}\$.

\begin{equation}
\omega = \frac{\theta_{i}-\theta_{i-1}}{T}
\end{equation}

We know that the largest error is 1 encoder step count. This means that the speed error can be computed as the following:

\begin{equation}
\omega_{error} = \frac{\theta(1)}{T}
\end{equation}

So the time between encoder samples and encoder resolution both effect error of your measurement.
Example: A 12 bit encoder has 1024 Periods Per Revolution (PPR). This means that there are 4*1024= 4096 individual steps. This means that each step represents 0.0878 degrees. Now imagine if you sampled this measurement every 0.01 sec.

\begin{equation}
\omega_{error} = \frac{\theta(1)}{T} = \frac{0.0878}{0.01} = 8.78 \frac{deg}{s} = 1.46 rpm
\end{equation}

So the longer you sample the encoder the better resolution you get. Typically, I use a running average to filter the numerical result (\$\omega\$), which reduces noise and provides a bit more stability for your controller.

Regarding PWM, I can't comment unless you are more specific about what you are doing. It is important to note that for your control algorithm you **must** use an integrator to reject torque disturbances and hit target speeds.

Answer (score 1):

PWM (resolution and frequency) does influence the velocity accuracy via the torque production.

velocity ripple is a form of acceleration (and deceleration) and this is influenced by the load inertia and torque.
\$T = J \alpha \$

For a stabilized system where the load torque equals the torque production, there is no more acceleration and a steady velocity has been reached.  However if there is any torque perturbation this will manifest itself as acceleration -> velocity ripple

Torque is current multiplied by the torque constant \$T = K_t \cdot i\$. So current ripple can produce torque ripple that causes velocity ripple.

When you control a motor via PWM your aim is to control the "average" current. There will always be a ripple as the current rises and falls

[image]

Higher the frequency, the lower the current ripple (and thus lower torque and velocity ripple)
[Selection of PWM switching frequency in BLDC motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/347032/selection-of-pwm-switching-frequency-in-bldc-motor)

Now what about PWM resolution? This also plays a part since the smallest duty is never small enough for the controller to exactly command the duty that is required to meet the command and thus what occurs is the controller will toggle between the two closes representable duty cycles. If your controller has a resolution of 1% then the controller will do something like this:  4% -> 5% -> 4%  if 4.5% was required.  This toggling results in smaller, larger, smaller voltage being applied to the motor and thus another source of ripple.

How much of an impact this has on your system depends on the update rate, the delta duty and also the propagation delay through interface chips.

Comment: Good point. It is especially true when the motor inductance is small, like the Maxon motors that use coreless stator winding.